# Can Not Click "Select Photos From My Computer" Button In Google My Business Using Selenium

Tags: python, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver

When trying to click on the Google My Business "Select Photos From My Computer" button I receive this error. I have tried using ever Identifying element type that selenium offers in the Documentation but cant seem to get this button to click.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "C:/Users/Office/Documents/Development/Web_Postmate.py", line 18, in <module>
elem6 = driver.find_element_by_partial_link_text("Select photos from your computer")
File "C:\Users\Office\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 338, in find_element_by_partial_link_text
return self.find_element(by=By.PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT, value=link_text)
File "C:\Users\Office\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 744, in find_element
{'using': by, 'value': value})['value']
File "C:\Users\Office\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 233, in execute
self.error_handler.check_response(response)
File "C:\Users\Office\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 194, in check_response
raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: {"method":"partial link text","selector":"Select a photo from your computer"}
Stacktrace:
at FirefoxDriver.prototype.findElementInternal_ (file:///C:/Users/Office/AppData/Local/Temp/tmpuv4pvvys/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver-component.js:10770)
at fxdriver.Timer.prototype.setTimeout/<.notify (file:///C:/Users/Office/AppData/Local/Temp/tmpuv4pvvys/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver-component.js:625)
```

Here is the Button HTML I have to use "Class" and "Link Text"

```
<div tabindex="0" class="c-F-U e-d e-d-Ac" role="button" style="-moz-user-select: none;">Select photos from your computer</div>
```

Here is my source file:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://business.google.com/b/101831927968068062215/photos/l/03416071574991367502")

elem = driver.find_element_by_name("Email")
elem.send_keys("User")
elem.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
driver.implicitly_wait(5)
elem1 = driver.find_element_by_name("Passwd")
elem1.send_keys("Password")
elem1.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
driver.implicitly_wait(5)
elem5 = driver.find_element_by_class_name("tx")
elem5.click()
driver.implicitly_wait(5)
elem6 = driver.find_element_by_partial_link_text("Select photos from  your computer")
elem6.click()
```

Comment: Hi.. As per HTML code it is div tag. Generally link text or partial link text will have tag a. So good to use xpath here. Just Google it u can find xpath creation with contains text if required. Thank you

Comment: I tried to use XPath and this is what I was able to generate "//id(':v')/x:div" Unfortunately this did not work either.

Answer (score 0):

You have specified `'...a photo...'` in your locator while in `HTML` source text contains `'...photos...'`

To use both `class` and link text try:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="c-F-U e-d e-d-Ac"][contains(text(), "Select photos from your computer")]')
```

Comment: selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Element is not clickable at point (622.5, 302). Other element would receive the click: <div class="a-k-h-fc-lm"></div>

Comment: This is the error I received when running your code

Comment: This is because `<div>` is not element you looking for!

Comment: I guess there is should be `<input>` or `<a>` element

Answer (score 0):

Try click by using Actions, in java like below

```
 new Actions(driver).moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(text(),'Select photos from your computer')]"))).click().build().perform();
```

if still it does not work, we can try by using javascriptexecutor

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(text(),'Select photos from your computer')]"));
JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element);
```

Thank You,
Murali